# logout user when the session time out

Tags: asp.net

Can this is the right way to log user out when the session timeout.
this is the code which i have written in Page_init of master page.
and also,
session state and Form Authentication is like,

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="1" cookieless="false">
    </sessionState>

      <authentication mode="Forms">
          <forms loginUrl="Default.aspx" timeout="2880"/>
        </authentication>


    if (userToLogin != null)
                {
                    if (Context.Session != null)
                    {
                        if (Session.IsNewSession)
                        {
                          HttpCookie newSessionIdCookie = Request.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"];
                            if (newSessionIdCookie != null)
                            {
                                string newSessionIdCookieValue = newSessionIdCookie.Value;

                                if (newSessionIdCookieValue != string.Empty)
                                {
                                    **System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.SignOut();**                                
                                    Response.Redirect("SessionTimeOutPage.htm");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
```

please suggest me this is right way or something is available as optimal solution.

Comment: Sorry, maybe needs more tests. I use this point to make test like that.

Answer (score 1):

Put your code in Global.asax.cs

```
protected void Session_End(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{               

  HttpCookie authenticationCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
  if (authenticationCookie != null)
  {
    FormsAuthenticationTicket authenticationTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authenticationCookie.Value);
    if (!authenticationTicket.Expired)
    {
       // log-out the user...                  
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: this will works but i want to redirect to another page after session timeout. and  Session_End gives error on response.redirect()

Comment: You cannot do that in this handler.. there is no request in the first place to redirect. You could write some workaround though..here (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15575/Detecting-Session-Timeout-and-Redirect-to-HomePage) is an example.